# How to return COLLECT([role, app]) using Neo4jClient?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have the following Cypher which I am struggling to translate into the fluent syntax:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r:Role)-[:ROLE_OF]->(a:App) 
RETURN u AS User, COLLECT([r, a]) AS Roles
```

This is what I have so far, but I can't figure out how to return the COLLECT([r, a]) as Roles. I am using a UserDetails class to enable passing the results to a View.

```
var results = _graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(role:Role)-[:ROLE_OF]->(app:App)")
    .Return((user,role,app) => new UserDetails {
        User = user.As<User>(),
        Roles = ???
    })
    .OrderBy("user.Username")
    .Results;
```

I first tried a dictionary, but Neo4jClient only allows returning as a `Dictionary<string, T>` whereas I want a `Dictionary<Role,App>`.

```
Roles = Return.As<Dictionary<Role,App>>("COLLECT([role, app])") // doesn't work
```

I also considered creating the following class to use, but I can't find a way for it to work.

```
public class RoleWithApp
{
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public App App { get; set; }
}

Roles = Return.As<List<RoleWithApp>>("COLLECT([role, app])") // doesn't work
```

I would be very grateful for some help with this, or a suggestion of a better way to do it.

Many thanks :)

Comment: I ended up abandoning the Neo4JClient due to difficulty controlling deserialization.  It is nice having the syntax help, but since the meat of the queries are free-text anyway I just started doing it manually.  IIRC it uses JSON.Net for serialization, so have you tried return as JObject?  Remember it's going to be a List of Lists. A dictionary is going to want to map Key Value pairs.  So List<List<Role, App>> might even work.

Comment: Thanks @LameCoder, but neither of those suggestions worked. I keep getting the error `"Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to deserialize into the object structure you supplied."` I have tried with JObject, List<List<Role, App>> and just object. I just can't figure out how to get this information. How do you do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the way Neo4j returns your query results, if you execute your query in Neo4j and download the json for it, you end up with something like:

```
"[[{\"RoleName\":\"R1\"},{\"AppName\":\"A1\"}]]"
```

JSON.Net has no way to know how to parse this, it would require something in the form:

```
[{"Role":{"RoleName":"Bar"},"App":{"AppName":"Foo"}}]
```

The important bit being the `"Role:"` and `"App:"` definitions which guide JSON.Net to the right place.

Unfortunately - there's not a lot you can do about that, even if you read the values directly as in @LameCoder's example - you'll have to do some hokey parsing relating to the order, or maybe the properties on the things you get back.

Of course, if in the future we can do something like: `COLLECT([role as Role, app as App])` then we'll be in good times...

Comment: Just saw latest blog post by M.Hunger, in one of the linked gists he returns results nested in a literal map. Never thought of it, but now wonder if it could be used to control the json response. This: `RETURN u AS User, COLLECT({Role: {roleName: r.name}, App: {appName: a.name}}) AS Roles` gave me `[{"name":"First User"},[{"Role":{"roleName":"Firt Role"},"App":{"appName":"First App"}},{"Role":{"roleName":"Second Role"},"App":{"appName":"Second App"}}]]`. Not good with Neo4jClient, can this approach be tweaked and used for OP?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone gives a proper answer for the specific driver the question is for, but since in the comments I was asked how to do it manually and there's not enough room to put this in a comment I've made it an answer.

This is very basic and should help you get started trying to do this manually.

```
var to = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher";
var reqMsg = new HttpRequestMessage("POST", to);
var cypher = @" ... ";
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

var req = new {
    query = cypher,
    @params = parameters //Use @ to be able to use a keyword as an identifier
};

var body = JToken.FromObject(req);

//You don't have to use streams if you don't want to. I just like to avoid creating large strings
reqMsg.Content = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
                    {
                        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
                        using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                        {
                            body.WriteTo(jw);
                        }
                    }, "application/json");

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.SendAsync(reqMsg, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        throw new Exception("Got status code " + response.StatusCode + " with error: " + s);
    }

    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())))
    {
        var o = JObject.Load(reader);
        return o;
    }

}
```